# Hi, I'm working on Power BI with some DAX, measures and tables to get last record with cumulative date due a range of dates here is the table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm working on Power BI with some DAX, measures and tables to get last record with cumulative date due a date slicer, I need to get consideration about the rows to consider their data by the date slicer.

[image: Base Image]

And what I want to get as result is according the date slicer if the dates will include by item, if date is <= 26/06/2018

[image: Data filtered by date and summarized by item]

And if date is <= 12/07/2018 looking for the latest date rows

[image: Data filtered by date and summarized by item]

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Hi Juan.  Welcome to stack overflow & thanks for posting.  You're collecting a lot of downvotes, and that can be discouraging -- especially since no one is telling you why.  Please check out 'how to post' (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to get a better sense of how to create a question that will get a useful response here.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Measures and slicers generally do not work well if you're trying to filter with a measure that is being filtered by a slicer.

See this DAX measure:

```
if(CALCULATE(max(table1[date]),ALLEXCEPT(Table1,Table1[Score],Table1[Percentage_By_Class]))=max(Table1[Date]),1,0)
```

This measure will highlight the most recent records (of all time) with a 1 and every other record with a 0. You can use this measure in visual level filters to highlight the latest set of records.

Unfortunately, it will not update as you change your filter with the slicer, making your table return empty.

The only solution that I can recommend is to change your date slicer to different type which is better suited to finding the records you are looking for.